# validate callout payload at webservice?

Tags: apex, callout, security

I am making a callout to web service. How can i validate payload received from callout at web service endpoint. is there anyway to authenticate that request actually came from salesforce only?

Comment: So do you actually want to verify the payload itself (i.e.the make of the JSON or XML or whatever you are sending), or just only allow certain calls to your endpoint (I.e. you only want calls to be accepted from Salesforce)

Comment: I don't believe this is a Salesforce question. The answer you seem to be looking for is related to authentication on your external server. Ideally, your external service would be blocked via an authentication protocol such as Oauth and Salesforce would have to authenticate itself and send an oauth token to your sevice to validate itself. We can talk to the SFDC side, but your external service needs to be set up first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SSL mutual authentication, where the endpoint can verify the certificate used, or you could use an IP address white list using the published IP address ranges for Salesforce. Both of threat techniques can be used to verify that a request is authentic.

Comment: in multitenant application, clients can be located in different address. IP address limitation will work on that?

Comment: @Rajeev They will be IP Address *ranges*. There are guaranteed IP addresses that the callouts will come from, although they may be varied within these ranges. See [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1) for a list.